# How to make header image resize with responsive WP theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to use the Enigma theme on my WP site.

It allows you to add a logo about 200px wide which works with the responsiveness of the site.

However, I want to upload a much wider image, which then resizes as the screen gets smaller.

I added a class to the image file and tried to target it with css

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

I am familiar with media queries but nothing I do is working.

Here is the theme, this is an example site, not the real site I am working on but it presents the same problem.

http://bestgirlsonearth.com

I've erased my work on it just to show the theme as is.

Comment: add important to the height `max-width: 100%; height: auto !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Due to fluid-system-column of bootstrap your image is located in a 6col "col-md-6" and by definition that class can't take more space or less than her parents middle weight (here row)

I'm not a user of Twitter Bootstrap but i think you should change in your header.php to have two rows and your full-sized img :

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">                    
        <div class="logo">                      
            <a href="http://bestgirlsonearth.com/" title="Best Girls on Earth" rel="home">
                <img src="http://bestgirlsonearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/bgeheader3.png" style="height:182px; width:1023px;">
            </a>
            <p>The finest women on the planet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <ul class="head-contact-info">
            //you contact info
        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

by this :

```
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">                   
            <div class="logo">                      
              <a href="http://bestgirlsonearth.com/" title="Best Girls on Earth" rel="home">
               <img src="http://bestgirlsonearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/bgeheader3.png" style="/* height:182px; */ /* width:1023px; */"></a>
               <p>The finest women on the planet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <ul class="head-contact-info">
          // Your contact infos
        </ul>   
      </div>
    </div>
```

cheers,